# Contar a quantidade de registros de cada tabela no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um Banco de Dados no SQL com 3 Tabelas, Comidas, Bebidas e Sobremesas.
Eu gostaria de criar uma unica query que mostrasse a quantidade de registros em cada tabela.

Eu tentei isso, mas não funcionou, acaba me retornando um valor totalmente diferente...

```
SELECT COUNT(Comidas.nome) AS Comidas, COUNT(Bebidas.nome) AS Bebidas,
COUNT(Sobremesas.nome) AS Sobremesas
FROM Restaurante.Comidas AS Comidas
JOIN Restaurante.Bebidas AS Bebidas
JOIN Restaurante.Sobremesas AS Sobremesas;
```

Output:

| Comidas | Bebidas | Sobremesas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 8 | 6 |

Comment: Qual a razão de ter feito o `JOIN`? Se a ideia é contar cada uma separadamente, o que esperava receber como resultado usando o `JOIN`? Chegou a pensar nisso ou apenas foi na tentativa e erro?

Comment: Você poderia fazer sub-queries. Não me parece JOIN seja necessário, possivelmente valores NULL gerados pela sua query é que afetaram o resultado, recomendo que veja essa postagem para entender quando usar JOIN e como cada um deles se comportam https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/3635... Sobre o seu problema, me parece que seja isso o que precisa: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/msEDZYpDUYfENMQhhd7BeD/0

Comment: Se você quer contar os registros das tabelas de seu banco MySQL uma dica é utilizar o information_schema. Veja se esta dica te ajuda
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-record-count-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

```
/*solução por union , em casos raros pode ser útil*/

Select sum(comidas) comidas,
       sum(bebidas) bebidas,
       sum(sobremesas)  sobremesas
From
(
Select count(*) comidas,0 bebidas, 0 sobremesas from comidas
Union 
Select 0 comidas,count(*) bebidas, 0 sobremesas from bebidas
Union
Select 0 comidas,0 bebidas, count(*) sobremesas from sobremesas)
Aux
```

[Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Answer (score -1):

Opa, tudo bem?

Qual seria o sentido dos joins? só para entender mesmo..
Enfim, tenta essa query aqui ó:

```
select (select count(*) from Comidas) Comidas,
       (select count(*) from Bebidas) Bebidas,
       (select count(*) from Sobremesas) Sobremesas
  from dual;
```